# Memory Leak in a Recursive Function

Tags: c, recursion, memory-leaks

I'm getting a memory leak and I know that for every malloc there should be a free. However, I'm not sure why we need to free anything here.

The function is to, given a binary search tree, insert a node to it.

The header file is:

```
typedef struct BSTNode *BSTree;
struct BSTNode {
      int value;
      BSTree left;
      BSTree right;
}
```

The program I've written to do this task is in:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "BSTree.h"

BSTree BSTreeInsert(BSTree t, int val) {

    if (t == NULL) {
        BSTree new = malloc(sizeof(*new));
        new->left = NULL;
        new->right = NULL;
        new->value = val;
        return new;
    }

    if (t->value > val) {

        t->left = BSTreeInsert(t->left,val);

    } else {

        t->right = BSTreeInsert(t->right,val);

    }

    return t;

}
```

The program output looks correct, so the logic is correct but it's just there's memory leaks.

The function is being tested on my school's servers, so it's running my function multiple times on different inputs and comparing it to expected outputs. The tests say my output is correct, just that there are memory leaks.

Comment: That’s not enough program to see the issue (there’s no `main`). The memory leak is when you forget to free the binary tree after you’re done with it. (Also, if being done with it is the same as being done with the entire program, no, you don’t actually need to free anything.)

Comment: There is a worse problem than a memory leak, though. When you do `sizeof(new)`, you’re getting the size of the pointer, not the size of a node. It should be `sizeof *new`.

Comment: I've edited the typo (the "BSTRee", sorry about that). The practice task I'm given is to finish off a function to insert a node into a given binary search tree. There's no main function that I can access because the automatic tests are on their system. I think what the autotests are doing is just running my function on a tree and comparing it to an expected output (that's displayed in a .txt file). The "sizeof(*new)" is written correctly.

Comment: 1) You haven't said exactly *WHY* the tests said there was a memory leak.  That would definitely be nice to know.  2) Of the code you posted, `BSTree new = malloc(sizeof(new));` is clearly *WRONG*.  You're only allocating space for a pointer ... but you're treating it like a struct.  Overwriting random memory on your heap.  Undoubtedly causing Bad Things.  Even things that might be interpreted as a "memory leak"...

Comment: I'm not sure why there's a memory leak, I don't have access to the main function or how it works. When I run the autotests (which I don't have access to the code of) it says "Correct output, but there are memory leaks being caused by your function". I've tried correcting the malloc code and it still gives the same error. Is there any further information I can give?

Comment: What’s the assignment description? Does it say that new nodes should be allocated with `malloc`? (Also, you might want to edit your question so it reflects the code you’re currently running, with `sizeof(*new)`.)

Comment: The assignment description (It's a practice problem, because I'm studying for an examination coming up) is to use malloc and insert nodes into a given binary search tree, outputting a tree that's still a binary search tree.  
What's weird about the return value? I thought it should always match the "type" of the function (which is BSTree). I'm pretty new to recursive functions and data structures.

Comment: Nothing, I was misreading it. Can you give the full and literal practice problem description? And do you know if the grading program is working for anyone else?

Comment: The problem statement was: "Create a function that inserts a node using malloc into a given binary search tree. Your function must return a valid binary search tree. Test your output using the given autotests."  
  
However, I've just solved it and it was the malloc(sizeof(new)) line. My old file was being compiled instead of the new and corrected file which is my own fault. Thanks! Noted that we should really be making "space" for the struct, and not the pointer itself (and the * dereferences it). Although, I'm not sure why with my original malloc code, it apparently gives correct output.

Comment: So you should just perhaps delete your question.

Comment: Shouldn't I leave it up for future readers?

Comment: @AnalyticalAnalysis1 what would they learn from it? There is no problem in the question - you can find the problem only by reading all the comments.

Comment: I vote for deletion, too. Just one more note: `new` is a reserved keyword in C++ and other C derived languages, don't get used to it as a user defined symbol. ;-)